# How to run ionic app inside angular using Html iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, iframe

I have managed to run this app locally.

https://www.ionicfirebaseapp.com/products/ionic-3-restaurant-mobile-app

However, the downloaded files allow to make an apk file of it, 
I am trying to make something like this demo.

https://www.ionicfirebaseapp.com/product/demo/ionic-3-restaurant-mobile-app

Can I please get a bit of guidance on how to make an ionic app runs inside an angular using Iframes, at least that what I get when I inspect it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210801/discussion-on-question-by-js-lover-how-to-run-ionic-app-inside-angular-using-htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in your ionic app :

```
ionic build --prod
```

The www folder which will be generated will be your app as js files.
Copy this folder an paste it inside your angular project in assets an rename it to ionic-demo and now you can access it from iframe using ionic-demo/index.html.
For more details about pwa from ionic docs :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/pwa

And this is a video to deploy it to firebase :
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D17S9cKSnfwM&ved=2ahUKEwj-2ePDosnoAhWBhXIEHZdyCDgQFjABegQIDBAJ&usg=AOvVaw3LxDt9qav_SIatfwN19RiF

Comment: I am trying it right now. I will accept it as soon as I get it to work.